# Why can't I `docker exec` after installing the official Django docker image?

Tags: django, docker, vagrant

I followed the instructions for setting up the official Django docker image, found [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/django). First, I created a scaffold for my project, by running

```
$ docker run -it --rm --user "$(id -u):$(id -g)" -v "$PWD":/usr/src/app -w /usr/src/app django django-admin.py startproject mysite2
```

Then, I followed the instructions for creating the Dockerfile, and after building the image, I ran the docker image with

```
docker run --name some-django-app -p 8000:8000 -d my-django-app
```

And [it worked!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5owx.png)

So just like the default page suggested, I decided to create my first app with

```
docker exec <docker container ID> bash -c "python /folder/to/mysite2/manage.py startapp polls"
```

But then I received the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/folder/to/mysite2/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
      from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

After some Googling, this indicates django isn't installed. But I'm confused; I thought this docker image was supposed to be shipped with django. I know django was used once before since the start page came up.

I thought the point of the docker image was so I didn't have to install django on the main system. How is `docker exec` supposed to be used in this scenario?

---

**Vagrantfile**

```
config.vm.provision "docker" do |d|
    d.pull_images "django"
end
```

---

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM django:onbuild
```

Comment: Please share the `Dockerfile` of your container

Comment: The documentation said my Dockerfile needed this line in it: 
FROM django:onbuild.
So that's all that's in it.

Comment: @mgansler I've added how my Vagrantfile pulls the django docker image above as well, if that's relevant. My Dockerfile with the one-liner is in the root of my django project, next to my manage.py.

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory probably isn't `/folder/to/mysite/` so django can't find the settings file to import.

In your dockerfile, set `WORKDIR=/folder/to/mysite/`, then simplify your run command to:

```
docker exec -t <docker container ID> bash -c "python ./manage.py startapp polls"
```